# Using CppUnit with Integrity

Tags: c++, cppunit, greenhills

I am not a C++ guy- but I have been assigned to evaluate some testing tools for it.  As an organization, we use C++ compiled with GHS Multi for Integrity.  We have an existing in-house set of testing tools that we have been using.

We are now considering a proprietary program that can generate unit tests and run existing ones.  The problem is that the existing test cases have to be in CppUnit format.  It was pretty easy to translate our existing code to the CppUnit syntax, but I cannot actually build it.  My first problem is that I cannot properly build the cppunit libraries.  I am restricted to a windows computer without visual studio.  I attempted to run the autoconfig configure script and it complained that no compilers were installed.  I have no idea how to point it to the GHS compiler, and with it at like 10k lines, I did not expect to be able to.  I installed GCC, but then I get syntax errors when I run the configure script.

Next I used cygwin to install cppunit directly, but am not sure how to get the linker to use it.  I tried adding the three libraries to the linker command, but that did not change anything... and I'm not sure if it would work even if I did it correctly since they weren't built for this compiler.  I stuck the .h files in a directory that the compiler checked, so everything compiles, but I get a bunch of unresolved symbol errors at link.

So- anyone with any idea how to build cppunit with the Multi tool chain, or to point it towards an existing set of libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say that you can build the cppunit 1.12.1 library from source on multi.
This is an old question so I won't get into the specifics.